# ASP.NET Core remove cache entry at a given time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
        ProducaoRegisto cachedRecord;
        // Look for cache key.
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CustomCacheEntries.RecordStatus, out cachedRecord))
        {
            // Key not in cache, so get data.
            cachedRecord = _producaoRegistoService.GetActivityStatusById(registoId);

            // Set cache options.
            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                // Keep in cache for this time, reset time if accessed.
                .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));


            // Save data in cache.
            _cache.Set(cachedRecord, CustomCacheEntries.RecordStatus);                
        }
```

I would like to invalidate this cached entry at 3 specific times.

6:58
14:58
22:58,

or basically every 8hours starting at 6:58

Is this possible?

Comment: You can invalidate the entry only once. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: For example, i would like to expire the cache at those times, those times will be set conditionally after checking the current time

Comment: The whole cache or just this entry?

Comment: just this entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you need

```
static TimeSpan HM(int hour, int minutes) => TimeSpan.FromHours(hour) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);

static readonly TimeSpan[] spans = new TimeSpan[] { HM(6,58), HM(14,58), HM(22,58) };

static DateTimeOffset GetNext(DateTimeOffset now, IReadOnlyList<TimeSpan> sortedTimes)
{
    var timeNow = now.TimeOfDay;   
    var next = sortedTimes.Where(s => timeNow < s).FirstOrDefault();
    if (next == default(TimeSpan)) next = sortedTimes[0] + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    return now.Date + next;   
}
```

To find the entry expiration date, call function `GetNext` with current time and `spans`.

```
var next = GetNext(DateTimeOffset.Now, spans);
```